# Playing FLAC, Ogg Vorbis and Opus files over DLNA to a renderer

Tags: windows-media-player, dlna, flac

I'm trying to play FLAC, Ogg and Opus files from my Windows 8.1*HDD to my TV** over DLNA.

Unlike MP3 and other files natively supported by Windows that work fine using the "Play to" feature of Explorer/WMP, FLAC&co don't work.

Installing the [Directshow Filters for Ogg Vorbis, Speex, Theora, FLAC, and WebM](https://xiph.org/dshow/) does not help (they allow those files to be played locally in WMP, but not to be streamed over DLNA - [turns out](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/flac/2016-August/001585.html) it is the fault of those filters).

I also tried *foobar2000* with the *foo_upnp* plugin, but its *UPnP Controller* component does not detect the TV, no matter what I try*** (a common problem with it, as I see on forums).

* Windows Pro 8.1 Update 1, 64 bit

** Sony KDL-50W829

*** turning firewall off, running it in compatibility mode, switching to Windows 10 and maybe others I forgot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of the [foo_out_upnp plugin](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_out_upnp) (1.0 beta 15) for foobar2000* works. It presents the detected UPnP media renderers as an output device in foobar2000 settings and by that does exactly what I wanted.

* - now I use foobar2000 v1.3.16

Answer (score 1):

[MFFLAC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfflac/) is a Media Foundation-based codec for FLAC. Installing that instead of a DirectShow-based one might be the trick to get Play To working.

Comment: It works, but of course only for FLAC files, not ogg or opus. I gave you a point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this soft for multimedia

Home media server:https://www.homemediaserver.ru/index.htm

For codecs that not readable use transcoding